# Force User Entry

Tags: vba, ms-project

I can't figure out how to reference columns in Microsoft Project 2013.

What I need is basically:

1. Whenever there's a change in active project in Column: = "Text 6" of a Task
2. If the task is not summary And the new value is not 0 Then
3. Pop up window ask for user input on how much time spent on Task
4. Place user input into Column: = "Work" for the same Task
5. End If
6. End Sub

Now if it was Excel I would use something like below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Work As String
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> 0 Then
    Work = InputBox("Enter time spent", "Time Spent")
    Target(1, 2) = Work
End If
End Sub
```